# Is the Drive SDK per user quota based on 100 seconds or 1 second denominator?

Tags: google-drive-api, quota

The dashboard indicates it's based on 100 seconds, but my utility was generating quota exceeded errors with <200 queries / 100 seconds (well below the 1,000 requests / 100 seconds default quota), and this was resolved by increasing the quota, which would seem to indicate that the quota is actually per 1 second.

The quota team wrote that a 10 QPS quota is equivalent to a 1,000 queries per 100 seconds quota. That's only the case beyond 100 seconds; this has implications for short-lived batch utilities and exponential backoff, which isn't useful on quota timescales of 100 seconds, but would be for 1 second.

Comment: Which API endpoint were you calling?

Comment: in addition to the dashboard quotas, there are short term rate limits. Can you update your question with the full response you are getting.

Comment: AFAIK, it can be both. 100 request per 100 seconds is equal to 1 request per 1 second. There are a lot of post regarding user-rate limit being encountered while still under the current quota per user. As stated in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17980687/5995040), there is a limit which is maybe lower than your current quota. Try following @Daimto's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29960685/5995040) on how to maximize the user-limit.